# Is $\mbox{Rank}(A + A^2) \leq \mbox{Rank} (A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Here, $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. I am not able to find any counterexample but not able to prove this as well. The examples I have tried so far shows me that $\mbox{Rank} (A + A^2) = \mbox{Rank} (A)$. I don't know how to show the inequality.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Does $\operatorname{rank}(A+A^2)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ hold if $A=-I$?

Comment: For now, I've TeXified your post for better readability. Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post.

Comment: Hint: $A+A^2=A(I+A)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Img}{Im}$

To show the inequality, note that $\rank(M)=\dim(\Img(M))$. Since $\Img(A + A^2)$ is a subspace of $\Img(A)$, the dimension inequality $\dim(\Img(A + A^2))\leq\dim(A)$ holds.

Note that equality doesn't always hold. Consider $A=-I$ where $I$ is the identity. Then $A + A^2 = 0$. Assuming $n > 0$, we have $\rank(A+A^2)=0<n=\rank(A)$.

Comment: How is Im of $(A + A^2)$ a subspace of Im$(A)$ ?

Comment: @FaqirChand: $A+A^2=A(I+A)$. Since on the right hand side, the last thing you apply is $A$, you cannot get anything that's not in the image of $A$.

Comment: What can be a good example to show that rank $(A + A^2)$ $ <$ rank $(A)$?